# What is the best solution making global service for S3 and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Im developing global mobile service communicating with back end server ( S3 - file server , EC2 - application server)
But i don't know how many s3 and ec2 are needed and where i should launch these.
So i'd like to know about below

1. Im planning to mount S3 in Oregon. As you know, CloudFront is the good solution for getting image quickly but the problem i wanna solve is uploading. I thought 2 solutions. The first solution it that using Put method to CloudFront, upload file to S3 through CloudFront. The second solution is mounting several S3 in different regions. Which is the better solution?
2. Now i am developing application server in only one EC2. I might have to mount several EC2s for global service. but i don't know how to make end users to connect to specific ec2 of several EC2s. Can you explain me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding of S3, is slightly off.

You wouldn't and shouldn't need to create "Geo"-specific S3 buckets for the purposes you are describing.

If you are using the service for image delivery over pure HTTP, then you can create the bucket anywhere, and then use a Amazon Cloudfront Distribution as the "frontend" whihc will give you approximately 40 edge locations around the world for your Geo-optimizations.

The more relevant edge location will be used for each user around the world, and they will then request the image from your S3 bucket and store it based on your meta settings. (Typically, from my experience, it's about every 24 hours for low serving traffic websites even when you set an Expire age of months/years.

You also don't "mount" S3. You just create a bucket, and you shouldn't ever want to create multiple buckets which store the same data.

.........

For your sercond question, regarding creating a "global service" for EC2, what are you hopeing to actually achieve.

The web is naturally global. Are your users going to be frett over an additional 200ms latency?

You haven't really descrived what your service will do, but one approach, would be to do all of your computing in Oregon, and then just create cache servers, such as Varnish in different regions. You can use Route53 for the routing, and you can also take advantage of ELB.

---

My recommendation would be to stop what you are doing, and launch everything from Oregon. The "web" is already "global" and I don't think you are going to need to worry about issues such as this until you hit scale. At which point, I'm going to assume you can just hire someone to solve this problem for you. It sounds like you have the budget for it...

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation 
what i really want to do is to improve the speed of upload, download and request to EC2…
I know what the cloud front will do and the web is already global
but as you know, if there is geographically nearer server(s3 or ec2) , the request and respond speed will be faster.
anyway, cuz there is cloud front, i don’t have to worry about downloading but the problem is upload

Comment: Actually, i try uploading to s3 oregon through CloudFront. but the speed is very slow… i don’t know why this result is occurred different from downloading
What i’d like to know is how to achieve improving request and respond speed for global service … I mean for users everywhere